# Find a row number, check if a specific column in that row is empty

Tags: vba, excel, is-empty

I have a series of workbooks that act as hourly data logs for our various machines.  Every hour, the operator enters their data, then clicks a checkbox, which transfers the data to a separate workbook.  Sometimes, the operator doesn't click the box for whatever reason, so I'm looking for a way to check if the previous box has been checked; if not, has a particular cell been populated.  If it has, the workbook would automatically check the box and submit that row's data.

So I'm starting with this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox03_Click()
If CheckBox03.Value = True Then
    If CheckBox02.Value = False Then
        If MsgBox("The previous hour has not yet been completed. Continue?", vbYesNo, "User Input") = vbNo Then
            CheckBox03.Value = False
        Exit Sub
        Else
        End If
    Else
    End If
    Call errorCheck(sht1.CheckBox03, sht1.ComboBox03)
End If
```

So I'm already checking the previous checkbox to see if it was clicked, and there will be times when a machine was not running, so no data needed to be entered.  The tricky part is checking to see if a particular cell in that row was populated.  The user can add additional rows to each hourly transaction if they need to add data, so I don't have a set row to look for.  I need to identify the row where the checkbox is located, then see if column "J" is populated.

I have 24 of these subs, one for every hour, and I know this is maybe a bit inelegant...but I can use this identical code in every spreadsheet, which is nice.  So if anyone can help me with the problem, or even improve the existing code, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: are the checkboxes tied to cell references? that will make it easy to find the row reference.

Comment: No, that's the real problem...the checkbox does several things, first it asks the user if they need to add an additional row, to include extra information about a particular hour.  So there is no set row for any of them.

Comment: if you tie each checkbox to a row, that will help you a lot. And if users enter more rows underneath with more information, the checkbox will still be tied to the first row. Even though that will change for checkboxes tied to rows below the added rows, you can still use the 'tied to cell` (don't know exact name) property of the checkbox to determine the row you are looking for through VBA.

Answer (score 0):

i do not precicely understand what you want ot achive, but maybe call the procedure instead of set value to checkbox.

```
    Private Sub CheckBox03_Click()
If CheckBox03.Value = True Then
    If CheckBox02.Value = False Then
        If MsgBox("The previous hour has not yet been completed. Continue?", vbYesNo, "User Input") = vbNo Then
            CheckBox02_Click(); // click specify buttion procedure
        Exit Sub
        Else
        End If
    Else
    End If
    Call errorCheck(sht1.CheckBox03, sht1.ComboBox03)
End If
```

Or in other case use Application.OnTime METHOD to Click te buttione on what time you need - for eg. every hour.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want the checkbox clicked if no data was entered during that hour.  That's why I want to see if column "J" in the previous hour was populated first.  What sometimes happens is an operator enters their data, then a shift change occurs, and they leave without submitting their data.  The next user doesn't pay attention, and the data for that hour never gets recorded.  So I ONLY want this process to happen if there was data entered in that line, not if it was left blank.